# How do I setup Zend Framework with WAMP?

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, wamp

I read that to include the Zend framework, I must include this on the include path in php.ini. But I have a doubt.

Where do I find the `php.ini` file in my WAMP with php 5.3.0?

Please help me because I am new to this topic and also to PHP...

Comment: check out this screencast: http://bit.ly/zf-wamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see the info you are talkin about (koen) but i wrote a simple helloworld.php in zend and i am tryin to run it so it takes me to a browser or it uses its own browser... but when i click the "run as php web page", it tells me it cant find the localhost(wamp), and when i even load zend newly, it cant find any server... well i just want it to connect to WAMP, and i wont mind knowing how it connects to XAMP, i run both services, but i would love to know more about WAMP, if you have any other suggestions please elaborate on it better... cos i am new to php and this zend framework

Answer (score 2):

Left click the WAMP icon in your system tray.  Under PHP, there's a php.ini option.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it from the index.php if you prefer. see the following code

```
set_include_path(
    'PATH_TO_YOUR_ZEND_INSTALL' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/models' . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() );
```

The manual of [set_include_path](http://fr.php.net/set_include_path).

Answer (score 0):

create a php file with phpinfo() in it. It will tell you a lot about the settings you use and also what php.ini file you use.